# program is not working as expected for prime and non prime

Tags: c, function, primes, definition

what is wrong in this code? please assist me
I am entering 9 it says that the number is prime
and the output is actually reverse of condition... how?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int prime(int);

int main()
{
    int num,res;

    printf("\nENTER A NUMBER: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    res=prime(num);
    if(num==1)
    {
        printf("Neither Prime nor Composite\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if(res==0)
            printf("\n%d IS A PRIME NUMBER",num);
        else
            printf("\n%d IS NOT A PRIME NUMBER",num);
    }

    getch();
}

int prime(int n)
{
    int i,p;
    for(i=2;i<=n/2;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0){
            p=0;
        } else {
            p=1;
        }

        return p;
    }

}
```

Comment: when you find the number is not prime , you should break the loop

Comment: Tip: You should check `if(num==1)` before calling `prime`.

Comment: Please indent your code consistently.  Strange, variable indentation and brace placement makes it hard to read.

Comment: @samini, Actually, they are breaking out the loop a bit too often :) This became obvious when the code was properly indented, which is why it's so important to do so.

Comment: Why `i<=n/2`? If input n = 23, it will never evaluate it?

Comment: Your if condition is wrong. If res == 0 then the number is not prime. and also it is better to traverse until square of the number

Comment: @Amadeus: if the input is 23, it doesn't make sense to evaluate the numbers from 12 until 23. It makes sense to check only until 11.

Comment: @Amadeus, the largest possible factor is sqrt(n), so there's no point in searching for larger factors. n/2 is serving as an approximation for that.

Comment: also you can use return when p = 0 because there is no need to traverse more

Comment: @LouisDurand Adding extra `return` statements and reordering the code is no valid edit. The code should stay "as is" with only visual improvements. Otherwise answers and comments may become invalid.

Answer (score 4):

The return statement is present within the loop

```
int prime(int n)
{
    int i,p;
    for(i=2;i<=n/2;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0){
            p=0;}
        else{
            p=1;
      }
            return p;
    }

}
```

So after the first iteration of the loop there is exit from the function. The function does not check any other divisors.

And for example for the prime number `2` the function gives a wrong result.

And the function has undefined behavior when the passed parameter is equal to for example `1`.

Also in main this condition

```
if(res==0)
    printf("\n%d IS A PRIME NUMBER",num);
```

is also wrong because it is presumed that the function returns 0 for non-prime numbers.

The function can look the following way

```
int isprime( unsigned long long int x ) 
{ 
    int prime = x % 2 == 0 ? x == 2 : x != 1; 
      
    for ( unsigned long long int i = 3; prime && i <= x / i; i += 2 ) 
    { 
        prime = x % i != 0; 
    } 
      
    return prime; 
}
```

See also the reference at my personal forum [C function that determines whether a number is prime](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-1-0-00000109-000-0-0-1541091687)

Though it is written in Russian you can translate it in English using for example the google service "translate".

Comment: `isprime()` can  fail for large `x` as `x % i > INT_MAX` is possible.  IMO a simple `if (x % i) return 0; .... } return 1;` (after handling even cases) than using `prime` would be more clear.

Comment: @chux It is enough to write prime = x % i != 0;

Comment: Good fix - many ways to solve